# C++ SDL Code::blocks: declaring pointer to global veriable in header file, while avoiding multiple includion issues

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks

I'm modifying the game state tut from http://lazyfoo.net. Got it to work as single .cpp; I've separated all my code into multiple files and am now running into an issue. I'm trying to initialize in **globals.h** file and then declare in **globals.cpp** file. Other **.cpp** files need access to the **currentState** pointer without multiple inclusion issues.

```
//globals.h
  cGameState *currentState;

//globals.cpp
  //Game state object
  cGameState *currentState = NULL;
```

I've tried adding Extern before the initialization in header file and it throws an error not liking the type. Is there such a thing as a global pointer? Sorry if I've used the wrong vocabulary I'm far from an expert, yet I feel so close; I'm still missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extern` is exactly what you want in the header file, but it needs to be lowercase E. Your terminology isn't quite right - your header file needs a *declaration* whilst exactly one (thanks to the "One definition rule") .cpp file wants a *definition*.

E.g. in the header file:

```
//globals.h
extern cGameState *currentState; // declare currentState
```

and in the .cpp file:

```
// this makes the compiler check the types match
#include "globals.h" 
//globals.cpp
//Game state object
cGameState *currentState = NULL;
```

Personally though I'd look to avoid having lots of global state in your application.

Comment: So even though I tried that before I gave it another shot, you never know. Glad to see I was on the right track even if success still eludes me. Right now I have...
// globals.h
// Header
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h" //Included for true type font recognition

extern cGameState *currentState;

#endif'

Comment: @user2052162 - best guess (assuming you didn't have `Extern` instead of `extern`): last time your tried it something else was wrong. Compilers aren't exactly brilliant at telling you what's wrong always when something unexpected is encountered. Possibly a missing `#include` or circular dependency.

Comment: What would you suggest to use instead of global states?